# m2eclipse filtering test resources

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, junit, filtering, m2eclipse

I am using m2eclipse and I want to right click and run tests from inside eclipse while the test resources get filtered from Maven. How can I do this? From eclipse when I right click on a test I do not get any m2eclipse options

Julia.

Similar to:

[Debugging maven junit tests with filtered resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855706/debugging-maven-junit-tests-with-filtered-resources/2856104#2856104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Setup filtering in your `pom.xml` (and you'll get filtering under Eclipse with m2eclipse, m2eclipse runs `process-resources` after a change of any resource).
2. Run your test as any other test (**right-click** then **Run As > JUnit Test**).
3. After a first run, you can run an individual test method (**right-click** on the method in the JUnit view).

Comment: I have set filtering as true for both process resources as well as process test resources, the problem is the values for the placeholders are in profiles.xml which m2eclipse is not able to pick up but when I run it from command line it works.

Comment: @Julia Oh, you're using a `profiles.xml` file. I don't recommend it and this `profiles.xml` is actually deprecated. Move the profiles into your pom.xml (or settings.xml).

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks. Just wondering if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Run As -> Maven test

Comment: I want to run a specific method in a TestCase